# How to optimize and improve neo4j cypher query with multiple match and an increase number of where clauses

Tags: performance, graph, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

in my neo4j graph database I have some Restaurants linked to Foods listed on the menu and also linked to the Cities where they are located.

I’m trying to search for restaurants in London each offering different kind of foods one from the other, so I started looking for two different restaurants in this way:

```
MATCH (f1:Food)--(r1:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(c1:City{name:'London'}) 
WHERE f1.name in [name1, name2, name3, name4] 
MATCH (f2:Food)--(r2:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(c2:City{name:'London'}) 
WHERE r1.id<>r2.id and f1.name<>f2.name 
RETURN, r1.name as Restaurant_A, collect(distinct f1.name) as Food_A,r2.name as Restaurant_B, collect(distinct f2.name) as Food_B 
LIMIT 1
```

but if I want to find a third Restaurant I need to add more where clauses and so on if I want a fourth restaurant, a fifth one…

This is the example for the third restaurant:

```
MATCH (f1:Food)--(r1:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(c1:City{name:'London'}) 
WHERE f1.name in [name1, name2, name3, name4] 
MATCH (f2:Food)--(r2:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(c2:City{name:'London'}) 
WHERE r1.id<>r2.id and f1.name<>f2.name  
MATCH (f3:Food)--(r3:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(c3:City{name:'London'}) 
WHERE r2.id<>r1.id and r3.id<>r2.id and f3.name<>f3.name  and f3.name<>f2.name  
RETURN r1.name as Restaurant_A, collect(distinct f1.name) as Food_A,r2.name as Restaurant_B, collect(distinct f2.name) as Food_B, r3.name as Restaurant_C, collect(distinct f3.name) as Food_C 
LIMIT 1
```

And I’d really like to know if there is an alternative way to do it, I’m new to neo4j and every suggestion is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you provide a collection of :Food nodes in an array, you could do

```
MATCH (f:Food)--(r:Restaurant)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(c1:City{name:'London'}) 
WHERE f IN $foodNodes
RETURN r.name as restaurant, COLLECT(DISTINCT f.name) AS foods
```

to retrieve the restaurants and their foods.